# Ndk include libraries

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a c code that needs in openssl. It works on my pc when i build it with `clang -std=gnu99 -o "main" "main.c" -I "/usr/local/include/openssl" -L "/usr/local/lib" -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lpthread -ldl` command.

But now i need to build it for android. I tried `/path_to_ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi24-clang -std=gnu99 -o "main" "main.c" -I "/usr/local/include/openssl" -L "/usr/local/lib" -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lpthread -ldl` but it can't include my pc's libraries.

So what is my option to do?

Comment: You need to build the openssl library using the Android NDK tool-chain.

Comment: @RichardCritten and how  ? Simply place it in project folder or?

Comment: See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android